# Azure Redis Cache - how connections are calculated

Tags: azure, azure-caching, azure-redis-cache

Can somebody explains how the connections are calculated in Azure Redis Cache?

For example if I have an MVC app and I use a Basic Redis Cache with 256 connections, and I have 256 users accessing my websites will there be 256 connections made? How exactly does this work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many connections are made depends on the application you implement.
If you follow best practices, your application will be able to handle many users with a very low amount of connections.

E.g. Stackexchange.Redis should be able to handle thousands of users without exhausting your 256 connections if you reuse the connection multiplexer object.

Some more information:

https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f

https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics

> the key idea in StackExchange.Redis is that it aggressively shares the connection between concurrent callers

Comment: Basically that's the reason why the redis cache is registered as a singleton in the DI (ASP.NET Core Distributed Redis Cache)?

Comment: Yes exactly. Because the controller is recreated for every call, you would otherwise need to use static or other means to keep the instance alive. It is also important to dispose the old multiplexer should you ever need a new one. Otherwise you can run out of connections on the azure side.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications!